# how can I disable the default keyboard shortcut in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

For example, <kbd>F5</kbd> will run the debug task in VS code, can I disable it by some ways? Especially by an extension.

I found there are many keyboard short-cuts extensions for VS code, but they only add new functionality for the editor, never disable a built-in one.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_removing-a-specific-key-binding-rule

Comment: You can press `delete` button in keybindings view (or through context menu).

Comment: good, you are clever.

Answer (score 0):

```json
// In Default Keyboard Shortcuts
...
{ "key": "tab", "command": "tab", "when": ... },
{ "key": "tab", "command": "jumpToNextSnippetPlaceholder", "when": ... },
{ "key": "tab", "command": "acceptSelectedSuggestion", "when": ... },
...

// To remove the second rule, for example, add in keybindings.json:
{ "key": "tab", "command": "-jumpToNextSnippetPlaceholder" }
```

SOURCE: [vscode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_removing-a-specific-key-binding-rule)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable a shortcut by going to
File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Select the the one you want to changes -> Click on any desired key
My tab key was pressed automatically due to faulty keyboard.
So I have disabled it using xmodmap, but still tab was working in VScode.
So I replaced the keybinding of line which says 'tab' under command section.